# How to get max value key from a list with each element of list is a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get `maximum value key` from a list with each element of list is a dictionary like

`li = [{'a': 100}, {'b': 200}, {'c': 50}]`

Is it possible to get `maximum value key` without sorting list? Please help me to solve this.

Comment: What exactly is your expected output for the sample data? What if any of the dicts has multiple entries?

Comment: Like for given list output should be key 'b'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `max`  built-in accepts a `key` parameter which can be as complex as you want it:

```
max(li,key=lambda x: list(x.values())[0])
```

If all your dictionaries have one item, then just get all the values, and retrieve the first (and only) index. Note in Python 2 `values()` returns a `view`, so you have to convert it to a list before accessing it.

Comment: Thanks **kabanus**. With little modification I got expected output as `list(max(li,key=lambda x: list(x.values())[0]).keys())[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the maximum value in linear time by accessing each element and saving the current maximum value.
Edit

People already wrote the pythonic way of doing it.
The non pythonic way would be to write a normal loop like this:

```
li = [{'a': 100}, {'b': 200}, {'c': 50}]

# if you know that all numbers are positive then just use max = 0
max = list(li[0].values())[0]

for values in li:    
    for value in values.values():
        if value > max:
           max = value
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Please post code that does what you wrote in words, and you'll get my up-vote.

Comment: Thanks **@tonedblue**

Answer (score 1):

this would also allow for more items in your dictionaries:

```
from itertools import chain
from operator import itemgetter
li = [{'a': 100}, {'b': 200}, {'c': 50}]
m = max(chain.from_iterable(item.items() for item in li), key=itemgetter(1))[0]
print(m)
```

i.e. it would also work if your list looked like this:

```
li = [{'a': 100}, {'b': 200, 'd': 50}, {'c': 50, 'e': 300, 'f': 20}]
```

you'd need to take edge-cases like

```
li = [{'a': 100}, {'b': 100}]
```

into account. should the answer be `a` or `b`?

Comment: Thanks **hiro protagonist**. This is a perfect answer in my use case two key with same value will be impossible and each dictionary is with only one key value pair. thanks.